# Am i still hopeful for Allah's forgiveness after this sin?

Tags: forgiveness, tawba, masturbation, day-of-judgement, hereafter

Salam i want to ask a question. I have been doing masturbation for 7 months and now i have left it Alhumdulilah and Alhumdulilah i also did tawbah and promised Allah i will never do that sin and and will leave it..but i just sometimes feel that i may not be forgiven because i heard that it turns your hands pregnant in the afrerlife please tell me is there any hadith that says that this will happen? And i am not even 16 and i got super scared after i heard this and that's why i sometimes think i am not worthy of forgiveness please i do not want this punishment in the afterlife please tell me will Allah forgive me? I prayed Salat al tawbah and promised never to return to it will Allah forgive?

Answer (score 2):

Allah the Almighty is all-forgiving, there isn’t a sin he will not forgive if you repent for that sin. The hadith you mentioned is non-existent and is spread to make people scared. But remember Allah and if you were to die whilst masturbating.

Comment: Thank you my friend